# How to change boxStrokeColor Of TextInputLayout in Android?

Tags: android, colors, dynamically-generated, android-textinputlayout

I dynamically create textInputlayout and add it to my lienarlayot using **the code below:**

```
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(10,10,10,10);
        til.setLayoutParams(params);
        til.setHint("Label");
        til.setId(i+1);
        TextInputEditText et = new TextInputEditText(til.getContext());  
        et.setSingleLine(true);
        til.addView(et);
        til.setBoxCornerRadii(R.dimen.CornerRadious,R.dimen.CornerRadious,R.dimen.CornerRadious,
        R.dimen.CornerRadious);
        information.addView(til);
```

I want to change boxStrokeColor , CursorColor and HintTextColor.

**I use the following code block to change boxStrokeColor**

```
 til.setBoxStrokeColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

But that code block only change the boxStrokeColor of TextInputLayout (white) when I click the TextInputLayout ,without click it's color is black. How can I set it's color white ?

Comment: Post also the first line, where you initialize the til, and the app theme used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a selector(`ColorStateList`) otherwise the single value will be applied to the box only if focused.

Use the method **`setBoxStrokeColorStateList`**

```
til.setBoxStrokeColorStateList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(this.R.color.selector))
```

where the `selector` is something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/...." android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/...." android:state_hovered="true"/>
    <item android:color="@color/...." android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:color="@color/...."/>
</selector>
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

**Note:** it requires at least the version `1.2.0` of material components library.

There is an alternative if you want to use a style defined in xml:

Define in `attrs.xml` a custom attribute:

```
<attr name="customTextInputStyle" format="reference" />
```

then in your theme add this attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.*">
    <!-- ..... -->
    <item name="customTextInputStyle">@style/Widget.App.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox</item>
</style>
```

Now you can add all the properties in the new style:

```
<style name="Widget.App.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/boxstroke_selector</item>
    <!-- .... -->
    <item name="materialThemeOverlay">@style/ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox</item>
</style>

<style name="ThemeOverlay.App.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox"
    parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <!-- to change the cursor color -->
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/teal_200</item>
</style>
```

Finally create your `TextInputLayout` with:

```
TextInputLayout til = new TextInputLayout(this,null,R.attr.customTextInputStyle);
```

[image]

Comment: my Box color is not change is still black

Comment: Alose when I change to version of the material 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 or 1.3.0  I get 2 render problem 2

Comment: @Neo You should check better the issues in updating the library. In any case you can still use the style defined in xml.

Comment: With version 1.1.0 I could input textInputlayouta with a single click, I have to click twice after changing the version to enter data and the format of the textInputlayout I created is broken.

Comment: How can change cursor color ? I use  <style name="Widget.App.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
        
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- .... -->
    </style>   but is not working

Comment: @Neo You can't use `<item name="colorPrimary">` in a style. You can use it in a theme Overlay. It means `android:theme` in a xml layout or `materialThemeOverlay` a style. About the cursor check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, you helped a lot. But I want to ask one more thing.  `<style name="ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined" parent="">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:hint">Number of player</item>     </style>`  <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout              style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.TextInputEditText.Outlined">  This use is correctly

Comment: @Neo yes it is correct, but I would avoid the use android:hint in a style or theme.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to work with `XML` instead all in Code.
You have to add this line in `colors.xml` file which will override the default color for the outline box.

Copy this line as it is. You can change color to what you want:

```
<color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color">#fff</color>
```

until now it will work, for more control on TextInputLayout you may add this style in `styles.xml`

```
<style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense">
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">#000</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeWidth">2dp</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:theme">@style/exampleCursor</item>
</style>

<style name="exampleCursor" parent="ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

Then add theme to `TextInputLayout`:

```
style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
```

Comment: I created dynamically so that I can't use android:theme="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"